# How to recursively perform an HTTP request in angular?

Tags: angular, recursion, rxjs, angular-httpclient

I need to make a get request to an endpoint which contains a list of posts and a key of total posts.

```
{
    posts: [{}, {}, {}, ...],
    total: 1000
}
```

the offset **key** for the request determines the number of posts return.

```
// request
https://postBalzer.com/posts?offset=0&limit=50
```

this request return posts from 0 - 50
How to make the call recursive until all the posts are fetched using Angular HttpClientModule.

How can I use the expand rxjs operator in such a case?

Comment: `https://postBalzer.com/posts?key=50` ?

Comment: I need to load in chunks, the whole list contains 10,000 rows, i need to pass the offset and limit size like 0, 50 then 50, 100

Comment: And what have you tried so far

Comment: currently managed to get the first chunks

Comment: I mean what have you tried to make your recursive calling.

Comment: I don't understand how to do it in rxjs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195665/discussion-between-anees-kodappana-and-maryannah).

Comment: I don't need to go in a chat. Honestly, this is the basics of coding and it doesn't even imply RxJS. If you can't provide at least a piece of code on what you've tried, then this means we're doing job, without getting the wage that goes with it ...

Comment: @Anees you need make something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56786261/recursively-combining-http-results-based-on-response/56787478#56787478 (well, you check not data.next, else data.length, but it's look like similar). An unique question: Why do you want to get 10000 rows at time?, it's not very efficient

Comment: It's actually a  hotels result. so when the user first visits the page, loading 10,000 response may take time. so we wish to download in chunks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done in rxjs by using the `expand` operator as follows:

```
import {HttpParams} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable, empty} from 'rxjs';
import {expand, map, reduce} from 'rxjs/operators';

export interface PostResponse {
  posts: object[];
  total: number;
}

@Injectable()
export class Service {
  private readonly baseUrl = '...';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getPosts(chunkSize: number): Observable<object[]>
  {
    let chunkOffset = 0;
    return this.getPostsChunk({chunkOffset++, chunkSize}).pipe(
      expand(({total}) => total >= chunkOffset * chunkSize
                                ? getPostsChunk({chunkOffset++, chunkSize})
                                : empty()
      ),
      map(res => res.posts),
      // if you want the observable to emit 1 value everytime that
      // a chunk is fetched, use `scan` instead of `reduce`
      reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), new Array<object>()),
    );
  }

  getPostsChunk({chunkOffset, chunkSize}: {chunkOffset?:number, chunkSize:number})
  {
     const offset = (chunkOffset || 0) * chunkSize;
     const limit = offset + chunkSize;
     const params = new HttpParams({offset, limit});
     return this.http.get<PostResponse>(this.baseUrl, {params});
  }
}
```

Considering that you can "calculate" the number of requests required to fetch all the post entries from the *total* value obtained after the 1st request, you can most definitely implement this in a different way without using the `expand` operator.

Answer (score -1):

```
getData() {
    if (this.total < 50) {
        this.service().subscribe((response) => {
            this.total += response.length;
            this.getData()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code has at least one serious issue. First time the function is called you will register a subscriber, second time another subscriber will be registered without removing the first. So each time the subscribers are hit, more and more listeners will be registered - causing the `total` value to rise exponentially in value. It also won't stop to increase just because it hits 50.

Comment: put a `.pipe(take(1))` before the .subscribe() then the subscription is auto unsubscribed and you are save.