# Return multiple HttpClients in Typescript, Angular, Rxjs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I need to make get request to multiple endpoints but want to return all by once. 
This returns a get request of a single endpoint:

```
public getTasks(): Observable<any> {

   this.logger.info('TasksService: getTasks()');

   const endpoint = `${this.processEngineUriPrefix}runtime/tasks`;

   // https://www.flowable.org/docs/userguide/index.html#_request_parameters
   const sort = 'createTime';
   const order = 'asc'; // 'desc'
   // const start = 0;
   // const size = 16;

   const params = new HttpParams().set('sort', sort).set('order', order);

   return this.httpClient.get<TaskListModel>(endpoint, this.getHttpOptions(params)).pipe(

     tap(() => {

       this.logger.info('TasksService: getTasks() completed');

     }),
     catchError(error => {

       this.logger.info('TasksService: getTasks() -> catchError()');

       if (error === undefined) {

         error = new Error(HTTP_SERVER_ERROR_CONNECTION_REFUSED);
         throw error;

       } else {

         return this.handleError('Get tasks', []);
         // return throwError(error);
       }

     })

   );

 }
```

To achieve this proxy.conf looks like this:

```
"/process-api-0": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8084",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/process-api-0": "/process-api/"
    },
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Basic Zmxvd2FibGUtcmVzdDp0ZXN0"
    }
  },
    "/process-api-1": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8088",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
      "pathRewrite": {
        "^/process-api-1": "/process-api/"
      },
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Basic Zmxvd2FibGUtcmVzdDp0ZXN0"
    }
  },
```

My Approach was to loop through but can´t figure out how to return: 

Note: Later, it should be possible to add much more endpoints.

```
const list = [0, 1];

  for (const i in list) {
    const endpoint = `${this.processEngineUriPrefix}` + i + `/runtime/tasks`;

    this.httpClient.get<TaskListModel>(endpoint, this.getHttpOptions(params)).pipe(
      tap(() => {

        this.logger.info('TasksService: getTasks() completed');

      }),
      catchError(error => {

        this.logger.info('TasksService: getTasks() -> catchError()');

        if (error === undefined) {

          error = new Error(HTTP_SERVER_ERROR_CONNECTION_REFUSED);
          throw error;

        } else {

          return this.handleError('Get tasks', []);
          // return throwError(error);
        }

      }))
  };
  return _________;

}
```

I noticed this post, but since I´m very new to this whole topic I don´t know if this is a approach for my case, respectively can´t customize it for my case.:
[How to recursively perform an HTTP request in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56801993/how-to-recursively-perform-an-http-request-in-angular)

Answer (score 1):

You may make use of RxJS's [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) operator to wait for the `for..of` loop to be completed before returning all the observables.

First, we refactor the HTTP request into its own method.

```
getTask(i) {
  const endpoint = `${this.processEngineUriPrefix}` + i + `/runtime/tasks`;

  return this.httpClient.get<TaskListModel>(endpoint, this.getHttpOptions(params))
    .pipe(
      tap(() => {

        this.logger.info('TasksService: getTasks() completed');

      }),
      catchError(error => {

        this.logger.info('TasksService: getTasks() -> catchError()');

        if (error === undefined) {

          error = new Error(HTTP_SERVER_ERROR_CONNECTION_REFUSED);
          throw error;

        } else {

          return this.handleError('Get tasks', []);
          // return throwError(error);
        }

  }))

}
```

Then, we carry out the for loop, and push the observables from each iteration into the list of obsrervables. When the observables from the requests within the for loop have been completed, it will be returned, and you can carry out the subsequent operations.

```
const list = [0, 1];
const observablesList = [];

for (const i of list) {
  observablesList.push(this.getTask(i));
}  

observablesList.subscribe(res => {
  // handle the rest here
});
```

Comment: Thank you for replying.
To refactor the HTTP request into its own method is good.

But I wasn´t able to subscribe to observablesList, do i have to declare it before ? 
````
const list = [0, 1];
const observablesList = [];

for (const i of list) {
  observablesList.push(this.getTask(i));
}  

observablesList.subscribe(res => {
  // handle the rest here
});
````

In addition i tried this : 
````

    return this.getTaskHelper(api++).pipe(
      expand(res => {
        return of(1 + api);
      }),
      take(2)
    );
`````
and get errors ....

Comment: @Crobrg did you declare observablesList?