# Rxjs recursive calls - concurrency

Tags: rxjs

I have the following sample code that recursively pulls the data from some REST resource.
Each endpoint serves the following JSON content

```
{ data: '123',  urls: ['https//example/bar', 'https//example/bim'] }
```

I can build an Rx stream that pulls the content recursively like this:

```
function getData(url) {
  return fromFetch(url).pipe(    
    mergeMap(resp => resp.json()),
    mergeMap(content => merge(of(content.data), ...content.urls.map(getData)))
  )
}
```

My question is what would be the best way to control the concurrency of HTTP calls here.

- Can this be achieved through a custom Scheduler?
- or should I simply wrap fromFetch into a class that controls the concurrency of how many HTTP calls can be in flight at any point in time?

Comment: Don't know if it is of any help, but [mergeMap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/mergeMap) can have a param that represents the maximum concurrent calls.

Comment: This sounds like poor api design to me, why are all the dependent calls not happening server side?

Comment: You can use rxjs `expand` operator [ https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/expand.html]. See a similar question is SO - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56786261/recursively-combining-http-results-based-on-response?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Ah nice i didn’t know about the project operator, will look into it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

With `expand` you probably only get maximum 1 concurrency, it is easier to control concurrency with subject + mergeMap so that you only have a single channel to work on.

```
const fetchSubject=new Subject();
fetchSubject.pipe(
    mergeMap(url=>fromFetch(url),null,CONCURRENCY)    
    mergeMap(resp => resp.json()),
    tap(url=>content.urls.map(url=>fetchSubject.next(url))
    scan((acc,curr) =>{
      return [curr.data,...acc]
    })
  )
```

Comment: yes this works too, expand does have a concurrent parameter as well. see https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/expand